Is the instagram_business_manage_messages scope required for the Instagram Business Login API?
In our application, we currently use the Instagram Display API, but it will be deprecated on December 4, 2024. We are considering transitioning to the Instagram Business Login API. However, our application does not include any messaging-related functionality, yet the instagram_business_manage_messages permission appears to be required to publish this product.
Does anyone know whether implementing messaging functionality is mandatory for using the Instagram Business Login API, or is this a mistake? Is it possible to publish the product without the instagram_business_manage_messages scope if the application does not deal with messages?


https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login/business-login#query-string-parameters says only instagram_business_basic was required, the other ones should be optional. But I couldn't tell you how this will play in review.

In the review process we're unable to "drop" it.
